# Is withdrawal Euphoria possible?

Tags: addiction

It is known that when the human organism is supplied with certain hormones and/or drugs that serve a certain function for a sufficiently long amount of time, he reduces, and may eventually entirely stop, production of those hormones. It is one of the reasons stopping drug abuse by going cold turkey is so hard, because the happiness hormones produced normally in the brain before, are now produced at a reduced quantity now and their neural receptors are atrophied too, so that their effect is even further decreased.

My question then is this: Could we reverse this? Create drugs with catecholamines or some other such hormone so we bombard a patient negative emotions so incredibly potent for an amount of time that after we stop injecting him with the drug, he's chronically euphoric? Maybe a way to kickstart the life of a suicidal person with depression, have them live at least a year or two in that blissful state of withdrawal symptoms to have them want to keep living, knowing it is at the very least possible to feel that way

Comment: Welcome!  It's an interesting question and I look forward to seeing the answers.  The obvious issue is that you have to keep a patient on medication for quite a while before the withdrawal will have an affect, and during that time, the patient will be far worse.  Therefore, far from preventing suicidal depression, you are rather pushing the patient that much closer to suicide for weeks or even months of time. Furthermore, I'm guessing the result would be relatively transient as compared with the treatment time.